# Determine if the series $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{(8^n)}{n!}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that it converges for n > 16 by the ratio test because I looked at the answer key but am completely lost by the answer keys work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What methods do you have?

Comment: What did you mean "converges for $n>16$ by the ratio test". Your index of summation is $n$ and all finite series ate convergent.

Comment: Integral test, comparison test, divergence test, limit comparison, geometric series, p- series

Comment: I accidentally made the index of summation to be n when I meant for it to be infinity, I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: The index of summation is still $n $.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the index of summation is what sits on top of the "sigma", if so and it isn't showing up, imagine this is an infinite series because that is what I was trying to get across. This is my first time using the website so I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: For the terminology see here:  https://math.illinoisstate.edu/day/courses/old/305/contentsum02.gif

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Your series is
$$-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{8^n}{n!}=e^8-1$$

Answer (score 0):

So you have $a_n = 8^n/n!$ and so
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
 = \frac{8^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{8^n/n!}
 = \frac{8^{n+1}}{8^n} \times \frac{n!}{(n+1)!}
 = \frac{8}{1} \times\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{8}{n+1} \to 0...
$$

Comment: could you elaborate on why you did this? I can't quite follow the work. What was your reasoning for an+1/an?

Comment: @PaulieIncapreo ratio test states that if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1$$ then $(a_n)$ converges

Answer (score 0):

As gt6989b pointed out: $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{8}{n+1}$$
When this subjected to ratio test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\vert a_{n+1}\vert}{\vert a_n\vert}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{8}{n+1}\to 0$$
This tells us that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{8^n}{n!}\right)$ converges.